# chrome-extension: send message to tab which has NOT been injected and then ignore "caught (in promise) Error: "

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The scenario is I have is

1. On 'options page' user can add / delete urls to block. When user clicks save button, the updated list of urls is saved on storage
2. On 'popup page' user clicks start button and all the urls in storage are blocked (by overriding innerHtml). On stop all the injected tabs are sent stop message (restore the original html)

Additionally on 'options page' when user clicks on delete a url and save, it will send stop message to all the tabs irrespective they are injected or not. the reason for this is that I do not know which url existed before and which have been removed

when i send message to all the tabs using code

```
try {
        let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({}) // all the tabs
        tabs.forEach((tab) => {
                const resp = chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type : 'StopTimer'})
        })
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('No matching tab', err)
    }
```

I get the following error for tabs which are not injected

> caught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving
> end does not exist.

I want to simply catch (ignore) error. to prevent showing it as error on extensions page. Right now this catch block is not catching the error.

Is there a way to do it? Else I have to figure out in 'background.js' all the tabs which have been injected and then send the message to those

Comment: Move try/catch inside forEach.

Comment: tried that also (i.e. nested try-catch) ...does not work :(

Comment: Add `await ` before chrome.tabs and replace tabs.forEach with `for (const tab of tabs) {` and add `async` to the declaration of the current function.

Comment: wow, great...thank you @wOxxOm. I will update based on your reply

Answer (score 0):

based on feedback from @wOxxOm, the way to handler request to tabs which have not been injected (by ignoring the error thrown back) is

```
async function sendStopMsgToAllTabs() {
    try {
        // we send stpo message to all tabs
        let tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({}) // all the tabs
        for (const tab of tabs) {
            console.log('sendStopMsgToAllTabs:tab', tab.id, tab.url)
            try {
                const resp = await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {type : 'StopTimer'})
                // console.log(resp)
            } catch(err2) {
                //don't care about this error
                console.log('sendStopMsgToAllTabs:err2 for tab', tab.id)
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('sendStopMsgToAllTabs: err', err)
    }
}
```